# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, orm, initialization, django-orm

In Django 1.7 this code caused errors in `django.setup()` :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    special_foo=Foo.objects.filter(name__contains='special')
```

In my case there I got this:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

But I have seen recursion errors in `django.setup()` trying to run `django.setup()` again, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with properties at class level.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    @classproperty
    def special_foo(cls):
        return Foo.objects.filter(name__contains='special')
```

Unfortunately python does not support `@classproperty` right out of the box yet.

I used the implementation from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191224/633961